# How to apply a CSS class to all instances of a control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui, webforms

I am trying to implement the jQuery UI framework for my ASP.NET project. And the way I thought of going about doing this is to just apply CSS to my controls.

For example, I have a bunch of GridView controls. Is there an easy way to apply a CSS class to all of them at once instead of using the "onRender" event on each instance like I have read online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .skin file that specifies the CssClass to apply to each GridView. See [ASP.NET Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) in MSDN Library for more information.

```
// In your App_Themes/SomeTheme/Default.skin file:
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="YourCssClass" />

// In Web.config:
<pages styleSheetTheme="SomeTheme" />
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when I create the skin file and add your line it give the error:  Unrecognised unrecognized tag prefix or device filter - asp.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is this error reported by Visual Studio IntelliSense, or when you browse to a page in your app?

Comment: During design time, underlined, IntelliSense

Comment: Code Project Link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11886/Themes-and-Skins-in-ASP-NET-2-0  this helped me out a lot. Just an FYI - if you don't want to design a style grab the formatting directly from the page WYSIWYG/Designer tool. Apply a format on a dummy control, then copy and paste it from the HTML directly into your skin file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a css class to all instances of GridViews is your ASP.NET app, you could look at the skin files for an ASP.NET theme.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx#ThemesAndControlSkins